# Easy way to sync key value information with SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, synchronization, cloudkit

I m working on a update for a `iOS` application where the user can see diffrent videos, so i also looking to add a `tvOS` Version soon.

I want to add a way to sync the "*watched*" status of a `VideoObject`.
My `VideoObject` does have a `VideoObject.id` and i would add a `VideoObject.watched_status`as `Bool`now i have diffrent ideas how to save these information and also maybe if possible use them on tvOS.

1. **Firebase** - This would require the user to create a login/me to generate a `userkey`, that he could sync with a other device (enter that `userkey` on other device), else the information would only be available on the one device.
2. **NSUserDefaults** - Maybe the easiest way, but not really flexible. Also no easy Sync avaible
3. **CloudKit** - CloudKit could be used to store these information (privat) and automatic sync these to other devices.
4. **JSON** - i could create a JSON File that is Stored as File in CloudKit/externalServer

Are there other ways to realise something like this? Without building a own backend?
Would you prefere one of these ways (currently i think CloudKit would be the best?), if so a short why would help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Hi from my point of view it is depending on the final aim of the synchronization, if you would like to synchronize simple data it is quite easy and reliable way to use **CloudKit** because of the simple API and well documentation that will show how to use synchronization on all Apple devices.

This [link](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/cloudkit-the-fastest-route-to-implementing-the-auto-synchronizing-app-youve-been-working-on/) contains nice tutorial that shows how to handle **CloudKit** in proper way.

If you would like have quite complex solution that contains a lot of highly customizable data you should use own server that will handle synchronization.

**NSUserDefaults** it is not best way to synchronize data between devices due to the purpose of that class. But if you would like to use small fix that will save videos that were watched this example is for you :

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(Bool(false), forKey:"videoIsWached")

var onoroff = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("videoIsWached") as Bool!
```

**JSON** file is quite old school way but it is not so flexible as **NSUserDefaults** and  **CloudKit**.

Also consider usage of the database frameworks such as **CoreData** or **Realm** this is good way to store local changes that could be synchronized with another devices via REST services.

In you're way usage of the **CloudKit** is quite appropriate due to the missing backend and option to synchronize with multiple Apple devices.